# Перебор данных на Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно перебор данных на Jquery?

Есть 20 section, внутри которых стоит h2. Плавающим блоком выводится список со ссылками на каждый section. Пытаюсь брать все h2 и вставлять в список, получается, что вставляет в каждый `<li>` все найденные h2.

Пишу вот так:

```
$(function() {
        $('section h2').each(function() {
            $('#fp-nav li a span').append($('<i/>', {text: $(this).text()}));
        });
```

**Обновление**

Мдя, из-за каши в голове фигово формулирую. Есть

```
<section><h2>Текст 1</h2></section>
<section><h2>Текст 2</h2></section>
<section><h2>Текст 3</h2></section>
<section><h2>Текст 4</h2></section>
```

Нужно получить

```
<ul class="list">
<li><a href="#"><span>Текст 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Текст 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Текст 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Текст 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Но у меня получается

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Текст 1 Текст 2 Текст 3 Текст 4</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать вот так, у функции `each()` есть возможность определять номер текущего элемента:

```
   $(function() {
        $('section h2').each(function(index) {
            $('#fp-nav li:eq('+ index + ') a span').append($('<i/>', {text: $(this).text()}));
        });
    });
```

**UPD.** [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2g4p1z71/)

Comment: Класс! Заработало как родное. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `text()` написать `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, что именно у вас не работает? Судя по коду, вы в список вставляете текстовое содержимое из h2, кроме того, вы должны быть уверенны, что li a span у вас присутвует.

Получается еще, что если они есть, и не один, то во все вставится ваш i.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9f23zp5/

```
$(function() {
        $('section h2').each(function() {
            $('#fp-nav ul.list').append("<li><a href=\"#\"><span>"+$(this).text()+"</span></a></li>");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Проверяем в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jk2gjm8x/1/)

```
$('section').wrapAll('<ul class="list" />').replaceWith(function(){
    $('h2',this).replaceWith(function(){
        return '<a href="#"><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span></a>';
    });
    return '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>'; 
});
```